# How can I have a 66MB job config in a job tracker while jobconf.limit is set to 5MB?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

How can I have a 66MB job config in a job tracker while `mapred.user.jobconf.limit` is set to 5MB ?

```
$ ls -lh /mapred/jt/jobTracker/job_201309061800_0037.xml
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mapred mapred 66M Sep  6 22:21 /mapred/jt/jobTracker/job_201309061800_0037.xml

$ cat /mapred/jt/jobTracker/job_201309061800_0037.xml | grep mapred.user.jobconf.limit
<property><name>mapred.user.jobconf.limit</name><value>5242880</value><source>mapred-default.xml</source></property>
```

Comment: Does the `mapred.user.jobconf.limit` in JobTracker is also 5MB? You only showed the configuration sent from the client (job_201309061800_0037.xml). This configuration is only applied to the current Job and is not effective to the JobTracker. You need to check  mapred-default.xml in your JobTracker.

Comment: Good point. The limit is set to 256MB in `mapred-site.xml`. Isn't it supposed to be overridable by the client ?

Comment: No, JobTracker will read `mapred.user.jobconf.limit` when it initializes. After that, this value in the memory (MAX_JOBCONF_SIZE in JobTacker) is not changed. You can check the code here: http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-cdh3u1/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobTracker.java#158

Comment: I have sorted out our discussion to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only showed the configuration sent from the client (job_201309061800_0037.xml). This configuration is only applied to the current Job and is not effective to the JobTracker. You need to check `mapred-default.xml` in your JobTracker.

JobTracker will read `mapred.user.jobconf.limit` when it initializes. After that, this value in the memory (`MAX_JOBCONF_SIZE` in JobTacker) is not changed. You can check the code here: http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-cdh3u1/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobTracker.java#158

I admit hadoop does not provide some mechanism to indicate which configuration can be set by a Job and which can not be set by a Job. Now my solution is searching the configuration in hadoop source codes and finding out how hadoop uses this configuration.